# Fetch Snowflake internal stageInfo

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build a tool that can send a stream of data directly to snowflake.

I don't want to be using an external stage and store it in my S3 bucket.

Looking into the inner-workings of the Snowflake NodeJS connector I have found the Snowflake [StageInfo](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/blob/fd9e5b3cccd9e99063aed80a47695515ca6cffe8/lib/file_transfer_agent/s3_util.js#L57):

```
  this.createClient = function (stageInfo, useAccelerateEndpoint)
  {
    var stageCredentials = stageInfo['creds'];
    var securityToken = stageCredentials['AWS_TOKEN'];
```

The stageInfo looks like this:

```
    const s3 = {
      locationType: 'S3',
      location: 'sfc-eu-ds1-9-customer-stage/xseh-s-eusb3446/stages/90eb373c-a612-4e37-854c-9f07ff16b2bd/',
      path: 'stages/90eb373c-a612-4e37-854c-9f07ff16b2bd/',
      region: 'eu-central-1',
      storageAccount: null,
      isClientSideEncrypted: true,
      creds: {
        AWS_KEY_ID: '',
        AWS_SECRET_KEY: '',
        AWS_TOKEN: '',
        AWS_ID: '',
        AWS_KEY: '',
      },
      presignedUrl: null,
      endPoint: null,
    };
```

Then I picked up those credentials using the debugger and started the upload on my own using the S3 Upload tool and threw it together to generate a stream:

```
    const upload = new Upload({
      client: new S3Client({
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId: s3.creds.AWS_KEY_ID,
          secretAccessKey: s3.creds.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
          sessionToken: s3.creds.AWS_TOKEN,
        },
        region: s3.region,
      }),
      params: {
        Bucket: s3.location.split('/')[0],
        Key: key,
        Body: ws.pipe(new PassThrough()),
        ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
        Metadata: {
          HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/octet-stream',
        },
      },
    });

    await upload.done();
```

Which worked great and I am actually uploading the file to the internal stage. Now my issue is that I cannot figure out how to get these `stageInfo` credentials from Snowflake. Does anybody know what request I need to issue to get this `stageInfo` from them?

Comment: Snowflake doesn't share credentials to internal S3 buckets as there is no direct access to them.  Have you looked at using the PUT command?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#uploading-a-file-to-a-snowflake-stage

Comment: @mike-walton yes I have looked at it and it requires me to have the file on the file system. I need to be able to stream it directly. I can get the actual credentials by picking them up myself in the debugger in the above mentioned code. So somehow it must be possible to get client side.

Comment: years ago we planned to grab the session continuation token out of the node.js connector to allow us to use AWS Lambda and chain a call, long poll, and complete lambda's to cheaply run 100K of queries a day. Snowflake were very adamant we should not use "private things" as they might change them in the future. We decided to follow that advise, and just ran node.js clients on AWS servers that had spare capacity and where always running. I think this is much the same, you can do it, but when it fails in production in the weekend, it's you rewriting your stuff, verse SF rolling a release back.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Yes, I am aware that there might be some development that falls on me from this. The issue is that I am running my system on AWS Batch where I am sending several hundreds of gigabyte per day. Having to store this on the filesystem before sending it. That will be a huge extra bill and slow down of the system.

Comment: @KristianBarrett So you know you pay for the "staging" files in Snowflake as they are "backed by S3 (or other provider)". The only way to escape them being on file (aka direct insertion command) you want to avoid like the plague because they are slow and compute costs more than disk

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Yes the cost is not the issue here. I want more control with what files go where. And Snowflake having access to our system is less desirable than me sending them to Snowflake.